# filtering data across sheets in excel

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I have some thousands of employee data in different sheets. I want to filter data in all the sheets based on the manager name through ADO.net. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you specify no.of sheets in your excel? so that it would provide better idea to optimise the solution

Comment: It is around 30 sheets with some 3000 records in each sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934) is a good place to start, particularly the links in the references section.

I suggest you create a `UNION` query of the data in all the sheets, and filter on that query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT F1 AS LastName, F2 AS FirstName, F3 AS ManagerName
    FROM [Sheet1$]

    UNION ALL SELECT F1 AS LastName, F2 AS FirstName, F3 AS ManagerName
    FROM [Sheet2$]
)
WHERE ManagerName = ?
```

Alternatively, you could also apply the filter at each stage of the `UNION`.

Pass in the manager name as a parameter.

Read the names of the sheets using `GetSchema`, and build the query dynamically.

Comment: It will be easy if there are 2 or 3 sheets. But is there any other way to do because I have about 30 sheets and it will be difficult to write this code for those many sheets